# Spring 3 JSF 2 integration example needed

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, spring-webflow

i want to Integrate Spring 3, Web Flow 2, JSF 2 together
and i need you to recommend me a good tutorial or example, thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

i used following example, and it worked fine with me with no problems:

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-hibernate-integration-example/

but it doesn't use spring web flow and i don't know if there are any problems with this approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently did a template setup of Spring MVC 3 using Spring controllers and JSF 2 as the view generator.

http://papweb.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/spring-mvc-3-jsf-2-with-maven-2-and-tomcat/

DISCLAIMER: My own blog.

It's pretty straight forward for the most parts. Where it gets tricky is if you want to use JSF 2 forms with Spring MVC controllers. I'm hesitant to say if that even works as JSF has a lot of state-management going on in the background that is not easily translated to Spring.

If all you are after is the component and layout/rendring-related parts of JSF 2, it should get you there.